# How to get access to an object between dynamically loaded packages?

Tags: delphi, package, global-variables, global-scope

I need to know the user name and other data of the logged-in user in a project organized using BPLs. That is, how and where do I need to declare the user object and its creation, and how to get access to that object when a package is loaded at runtime? I don't have enough experience working with packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a regular app, for the programmer there is no difference between using runtime packages or all in a single exe
You can change the project to go with runtime packages or not, and your code won't change at all

That changes when you make a modular app that loads BPL modules on demand, chosing at runtime if a given module will be load, and doing it dynamically (ex. app made with a plugin-architecture in mind), then you need to design your own strategy to handle that

Myself, I work in that second way, and I do have some main modules wich give services to the "plugins", so when they are loaded, they do register themselves with the system: user control, navigation, whatever

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special to use objects in a package. You just add the unit name where the object is defined to the uses clause of the unit where the object is to be used.

You should really read [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Packages_(Delphi)) on this topic. The you may ask more questions to clarify things you don't understand.